# javascript checking empty asp.net textboxt using button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

so i want to check if the textbox filled or no when i click submit button

and so far i only have this script on my mind, btw i'm new at javascript, here is my code :

```
  function checkTextField(field) {
        if (field.value == '') {
            alert("Field is empty");
        }
    }

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPOno" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtShipto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="text"  id="txtRRDate" name="txtRRDate">
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in [Validation Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bwd43d0x.aspx) from asp.net.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This field is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```